# Not able to get utm_source parameter from URL

Tags: php, get, url-parameters, utm

I am trying to get all the GET parameters, but I am not able to get them. Array is empty. The same I tried in a different server where it is working without any issue. Can anyone please help in solving this. I am wondering where could be the problem ?

http://example.com/test.php?utm_source=google&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=X&utm_content=Register

It is very strange that I am able to get same parameters through POST method.

Below is the code I am using.

```
<?php

echo "Method 1<br/>";
print_r($_REQUEST);

echo "<br/>Method 2<br/>";
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

echo "<br/>Method 3<br/>";
var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Comment: Can you show us what your code looks like? What have you tried already?

Comment: Please show us the URL and the code you have used to get the value from URL.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi I cannot share the URL here as it is related to a project, but the URL is same as the one I posted in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your GET params by doing this:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Or you can also check:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Comment: Hi @lloicono thanks for the reply. I tried them but no use.

Comment: Can you update your question and show us the code you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

First you should check you form type if is it a get type to get $_GET values

Comment: I am not using any form. I am trying to send parameters through URL as I posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late. but maybe this answer helps another developer.

```
// get the value of outlink, source, campaign, medium, content

let url = new URL(window.location.href);
    let outlink = url.searchParams.get('outlink'), 
        utmSource = url.searchParams.get('utm_source'),
        utmCampaign = url.searchParams.get('utm_campaign'),
        utmMedium = url.searchParams.get('utm_medium'),
        utmContent = url.searchParams.get('utm_content');
        console.table( { outlink , utmSource, utmCampaign, 
        utmMedium,utmContent});
```